# Visual C# Window Behaver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a form which instances a new form that I've already created using

```
statuswindow statwin = new statuswindow();
statwin.ShowDialog();
return statwin;
```

This code is in a function. The problem is when I run the function in other code the next line of code doesn't run until the newly instanced window is closed by the user, I'm guessing this is the side-effect of using `ShowDialog()`, is there a way to have it use the same behaver (being topmost, not being to select the other main window) while still letting the main form's code run?

**Update:** Although Show(); will work, I need to be able to make the window like a dialog by having it always on top of the other window and it always being the active selected window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ShowDialog method of showing a window shows it as a dialog, which is a blocking mechanism within C#/.net.  If you want to simply display the window and not cause the running code to block until it is closed, you can use the window.Show() function.

In your code:

```
startwin.Show();
```

This will cause the startwin form to become visable to the user, and will fire the startwin.VisibleChanged event as well as the startwin.Load event to fire.

Comment: Not quite the answer I was looking for, but useful. Do you know of a way to make the window always on top of the other window like a dialog? Also is there a way to make the new window run in a separate thread?

Comment: Check out the documentation for thread @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx that should help you get started with threads (just make a new thread which shows the window).

You can make the window stay on top using the Form.BringToFront method, you may need to overload a few events to call that method when appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

To make the new window always on top, you could set the Topmost window flag in the form properties.
To make the window run in a separate thread, first spawn the thread, then create the window from that thread.
There are also "application modal" and "system modal" Win32 window flags, but I don't know if those are exposed to WinForms or not -- go have a look on the form properties!